# installing X11 header file

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to compile GAMIT/GLOBK software and there are some prerequisites need. One of them are X11 library (libX11.a, libX11.so, or LibX11.dylib) and X11 header file (Xlib.h). I installed X11 library via "sudo apt install libX11 -dev" but I cannot find the way to install X11 header file (Xlib.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find packages containing a file using the web interface http://packages.ubuntu.com

Here's the result for all packages containing Xlib.h:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Xlib.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

Comment: I already installed libX11 -dev which contains Xlib.h but I cannot find where this file locates.

Comment: ok, I got it. I just searched with sudo su and I found it.